# How to get notification/log applet about copying files for the "Files" ubuntu unity desktop?

Tags: unity, nautilus, gui, notification, nautilus-extensions

I need a notification/log applet to copy files in the ubuntu unity desktop environment "Files" (also known as Nautilus), the default file manager. Due to the fact that files from ext4 to fat32 are copied for a very long time, i left sytem and so I can't keep track of whether the copying was successful there is also no indication of how long the copying took. Right now I can use bash script for copying but I would prefer gui nautilus using.

Comment: Due to the fact that files from ext4 to fat32 are copied for a very long time ... Can you clarify what this means?

Comment: @David, I just want to find a more convenient way to copy a large queue of files using nautilus. It seems that @vanadium correctly pointed out that this is not possible yet. By convenience, I mean access to the report on the copying process. Yes, I can do something like this  in the terminal ```bash myscript.sh <path to copy from> <path to copy to> --show-me-progress```, but it's definitely harder than doing mouse right-click in nautilus and choosing copyto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, such applet is not available in the file manager. If copy operations are successfully finished, the progress indicator will disappear shortly thereafter. However, if there are errors, an error dialog will awaiting you to inform you about that. So it is implemented as "no news is good news".

I agree with you that that should be better. A notification could be stored in the notification center, confirming a successful copy. However, it will require a feature request to have something like that implemented.

For lengthy copies, use of the terminal is likely preferred. Then you can store the messages of the command in a log file. Consider using `rsync` for large copy operations.